# Superposition d’un plan visuel et d’une séquence audio n’appartenant pas au même temps

Tags: choix-de-mot, lexique

Comment nomme-t-on (terme technique du cinéma) la superposition d’un plan visuel présent avec les voix (séquence audio) du prochain plan visuel?

Plan visuel antérieur avec les voix des personnages qui, chronologiquement parlant, accompagneront le prochain plan visuel (prochaine scène).

J’ai de la peine à donner corps à ce que je souhaite exprimer ce soir (la fatigue en est la cause) , vous pouvez me reprendre dans vos propres mots avant de me donner une réponse.

Comment: Cette fiche explicative du [vocabulaire](https://apprendre-le-cinema.fr/vocabulaire-de-lanalyse-filmique-53-termes-expliques/) cinématographique parle simplement de *décalage sonore*.

Comment: Attention : ...nomme-**t**-on...

Comment: Il me semble effectivement qu'il y a un terme spécifique pour désigner cela.

Comment: @XouDo Ah, je n'avais pas compris la question. Il s'agit d'un effet voulu !

Comment: Un fondu audio décalé ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'anticipation du son par rapport à l'image lors du passage d'une scène à une autre est un effet que l'on rencontre couramment au cinéma.

Après quelques recherches, voici les termes qui semblent les plus courants :

- **décalage (sonore) par anticipation**

> Décalage (sonore) : le **décalage** du son se fait **par anticipation ou par prolongation**. Dans le cas de l’anticipation, on entend le son avant de voir l’action qui va avec. Dans le cas de la prolongation, le son d’un plan se poursuit sur le plan suivant.

https://apprendre-le-cinema.fr/vocabulaire-de-lanalyse-filmique-53-termes-expliques/

- **chevauchement (par anticipation)**

> Au cinéma et en réalisation audiovisuelle, un **chevauchement** consiste au montage à
> faire déborder le son d'un plan (cinéma), d'une séquence (cinéma), ou
> d'une scène (cinéma) dans le plan, la séquence ou la scène qui précède
> ou qui suit.

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevauchement_(homonymie)

> « La règle traditionnelle du montage son-image en **chevauchement**, où le
> son déborde souvent, **par retard ou par anticipation**, les limites du
> plan  visuel, (...) conforte   cette   fonction   de   colle   à  image donnée au son (...).

https://dumas.ccsd.cnrs.fr/dumas-00942340/document